# trouble running UIKit Catalog swift sample code

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to run the code from the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/uikit_catalog_creating_and_customizing_views_and_controls

However when I try to run the code, I am given an error that states, Ambiguous use of 'configurationPreferringMulticolor()'. How can I resolve this error and run the sample code? I have attached a screenshot of where the error occurs in the code. [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yay62.jpg).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Xcode and macOS are you running?

Comment: I just updated to Version 13.0

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Mac OS Big Sur 11.6

Comment: And you're running it as a catalyst app? Given that `configurationPreferringMulticolor` isn't available until macCatalyst 15.0, I'd bet you have to be running Monterey.

Comment: I was running it as an iOS app for iOS 15.

Comment: Use `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration.preferringMulticolor()`instead. 